# What is JsonResponseMixin? How they work with the class based views

Tags: python, json, django, mixins

I have read about mixins and understood that A mixin is a special kind of multiple inheritance and provide a lot of optional features for a class.
Now i want to know what are JsonResponseMixin and why they are used.

```
class JsonResponseMixin(object):

    def render_to_json_response(self,context,**response_kwargs):
        return JsonResponse(context,**response_kwargs)

    def get_data(self,context):
        return context
```

This is the code i found in mixin.py .Can someone please expain why this is used .Are they used in serializing data?Please elaborate

Answer (score 3):

It's basically an abstraction to send a Json Response.  If you want to send a valid Json response, you need to convert your data to Json and send the proper headers.

In this case, JsonResponseMixin will do that for you and you only need to return an json serializable object.